# Running python functions from anywhere in command line

Tags: python

So, I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pADvJUafZZc&t=295s) tutorial on Youtube. This person is running python commands from the shell.

-TLDR;

He has a function called `nfe(args1, args2...)` in a `notes.py` file in some directory.

However, he is able to call the `kalles-Mackbook-Pro:~ kalle$ nfe args...` from his shell (on his mac)

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place an executable `nfe` on your `PATH` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/usr/python

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/notes/')

from notes import nfe

sys.exit(nfe(*sys.args[1:]))
```

This process can be automated by creating a package and registering [console-script entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation):

```
setup(
    ...,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'nfe = my_package.notes:nfe',
        ]
    }
)
```